# link not work in Bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code :

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="dis-rclick" data-target="#rightclickAlert">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Translator</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="label-info" style="display: none">
        <a href="tr-list.php?edit=<?php echo $usr['id']; ?>">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li class="label-danger">
        <a href="tr-list.php?dis=<?php echo $usr['id']; ?>">Disable</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I open the drop down list and click on any item i don't get any response.

For example: When I click on Edit I want to reload page but that doesn't work.

Whats wrong?

Comment: check your browser console for errors

Comment: I think the problem is in your php code inside the a tag

Comment: Did you checked browser console for possible error messages?

Comment: No any error ! i try without php and again not work !

Comment: With click only drop down closed ! :(

Comment: In <li> for Edit why have you given "style=display : none". If you give so then the list will Edit option will not get displayed.

Comment: @AKSHAYJAIN that's not important now ! I know , and that's for test

Comment: also i know that's work with this code ! `onclick="location.href='tr-list.php?dis=<?php echo $usr['id']; ?>'"` :(